# Build errors with Visual C++ 2015 cross-platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the new cross-platform tools in Visual C++ 2015 to build a native shared library for Android.

I had the NDK (r10d) installed before installing VS2015 so I chose not to install the NDK in VS's secondary installer. Instead, after installation I set the NDK path under `Tools > Options > Cross Platform > Android`.

I had a problem with VS not finding the toolchain binary - it was looking for `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe` under `[NDK_ROOT]\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows\bin` while in my installation the file was in `[NDK_ROOT]\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin`. To remedy that I just renamed the **windows-x86_64** directory to **windows**.

Now the problem is that build errors do not propagate to the Error List view. Instead, I get a single error in the Error List:

```
Severity    Code    Description                                         Project         File                                                                                                        Line    Source
Error       MSB6006 "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe" exited with code 1. pexeso-android  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application Type\Android\1.0\Android.Common.targets  194     Build
```

The only place I can view the actual errors is in the output window:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Dev\Android\android-sdk
ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
NDK_ROOT=C:\Dev\Android\android-ndk-r10d
pch.h
PexesoAndroid.cpp
PexesoAndroid.cpp: In function 'jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)':
PexesoAndroid.cpp:7:9: warning: unused variable 'jcPexeso' [-Wunused-variable]
  jclass jcPexeso;
         ^
PexesoAndroid.cpp: In constructor 'PexesoAndroid::PexesoAndroid(JNIEnv*)':
PexesoAndroid.cpp:26:2: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(jstring) {aka void (*)(_jstring*)}' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
  };
  ^
PexesoAndroid.cpp:24:18: warning: unused variable 'method_table' [-Wunused-variable]
  JNINativeMethod method_table[] = {
                  ^
PexesoAndroid.cpp: In function 'jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)':
PexesoAndroid.cpp:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

But this view is quite useless since, for instance, I cannot double click an error and have the IDE jump to the relevant line and source file.

Is this really what they meant when they said VS will be cross-platform?